# boto3.update_item is including the datatype specification as the value

Tags: boto3

If you go the update_item doc under `ExpressionAttributeValues` it says that you need to specify the data type along with the value itself: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/client/update_item.html

```
Use the : (colon) character in an expression to dereference an attribute value. For example, suppose that you wanted to check whether the value of the ProductStatus attribute was one of the following:

Available | Backordered | Discontinued

You would first need to specify ExpressionAttributeValues as follows:

{ ":avail":{"S":"Available"}, ":back":{"S":"Backordered"}, ":disc":{"S":"Discontinued"} }
```

However when I did this with the following query, the maps themselves were added as the value. For example:

```
    update_expression = (
        "SET #s = :status"
    )
    query_execution_table.update_item(
        Key={"ppid": ppid, "dataset_name": dataset_name},
        UpdateExpression=update_expression,
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ":status": {"S": "RUNNING"},
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            "#s": "status"
        }
    )
```

Would add `{"S": "RUNNING"}` to ddb instead of `"RUNNING"`. If I get rid of the data type, it works fine.

```
    update_expression = (
        "SET #s = :status"
    )
    query_execution_table.update_item(
        Key={"ppid": ppid, "dataset_name": dataset_name},
        UpdateExpression=update_expression,
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ":status": "RUNNING",
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            "#s": "status"
        }
    )
```